# My chilies look weak, what is the problem?

Tags: diagnosis, chili

My chilies do not look good since a couple of weeks.

- They look generally weak: the leaves are quite pale/yellowy, and many drooping or even falling.
- Some leaves are turning all black starting from the exterior.
- Many are not growing anymore since a month or two.

What do you think is going on? What can I do?

[image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sitting in water is the kiss of death for most plants.  Is this potting soil you've used in your pots?  And sure looks as if you haven't used any basic balanced fertilizer?  NPK?

Are these plants on a window sill inside your home?  Light from even a south window will not be enough to produce flowers and fruit and vigor.  Do you have a covered porch?  Putting them out of doors under a roof or awning that protects the plants from direct sun might make a difference. Don't move them from indoors to out of doors without complete protection from the sun at this point.  Do you have an area as a garden?  We can explain how to acclimate your peppers to the out of doors sunlight.

Get rid of all water in the bottom of that tray, lift the bottoms of the pots off the surface of those trays so water can drain out of your pots, use a basic fertilizer such as Osmocote 14-14-14 or Dr. Earth's All purpose 5-5-5.

Comment: Adding a little sulpur to the soil also helps peppers, but get them out of that water first.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a number of reasons:
Overwatering 
Disease
Too much fertiliser 
Poor compost mix

I see your plants are on a basin. Are the roots always in water?  Can you give more details on how you look after the plant?

However, Black leaves usually is a sign of plant failing which will lead to death.